# angular-chart and chartjs in bower component does not find each other

Tags: angularjs, charts, gulp

I want to work with [angular-chart](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js) in my project so I have installed chart.js and angular-chart js with bower  with following steps

- add in *.bowerrc*

  ```
   {
     "resolvers": [
           "bower-npm-resolver"
     ]
   }
  ```

and than

`npm install -g bower-npm-resolver`

`bower install npm:chart.js --save`

`bower install --save angular-chart.js`

my ***bower_components*** folder also have `angular-chart.js`  and  `chart.js` folder

```
|-- angular
|-- angular-chart.js
|-- chart.js
```

as I do not add anything in index.html ,  gulp automatically add all bower  when I run `gulp serve` components js in index.html when render ( see below )

```
   <script src="../bower_components/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
   <script src="../bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
```

it gives errors  in console

> chart.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>   angular-chart.js:23 Uncaught Error: Chart.js library
>   needs to be included, see http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Comment: same issue here  : https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after installing with Bower.

The solution as proposed in https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/466 was to get specific versions of chart.js and angular-chart.js (tested with angular 1.4.0)

Edit your `bower.json` file to match these versions:

```
"chart.js": "npm:chart.js#2.1.0",
"angular-chart.js": "1.0.1"
```

and then run: `bower uninstall angular-chart.js chart.js` to un-install conflicting versions and finally run `bower install` to install the required versions.

Comment: I have updated version with angular 1.5.8 
 `"chart.js": "npm:chart.js#^2.2.1",
 "angular-chart.js": "^1.0.2"`

I just change in bower.json as per suggested in that github issue and it's working now